# Clean windows and ubuntu to free up disk space

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Is there any other way to free up disk space on windows xp and on ubuntu 9.10 removing unnecessary files and folders/directories?

For windows, as far as I know I use Disk cleanup, Disk Defragment, and removing cookies and histories from IE browser. Is there any other way to clean up apart from these.

The ubuntu cloud server has left only 900MB of disk space. I'll just empty the directory /tmp and wondering if there is any other location to clean up.

Comment: Better suited to SuperUser? It would automigrate if voted to close.

Comment: Or ask on the ubuntu version of this site: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: http://maketecheasier.com/8-ways-to-maintain-a-clean-lean-ubuntu-machine/2008/10/07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `du` to investigate which directories are using the most space.  I typically run `du` repeatedly, working my way down the file hierarchy to find if I have any large files that I no longer need and have forgotten about.

```
du -sch /*
```

Then, if I see /var is taking up a lot of space, I'll du in that directory:

```
du -sch /var/*
```

... etc.

You can also clean up downloaded packages (.debs) that are cached by apt.

```
apt-get clean
```